# LINQ query needed using a conditional operand in the WHERE clause

Tags: c#, linq, comparison-operators, operands

I am having trouble composing a LINQ statement that uses a conditional operand within the where clause and have looked through this site for a similar problem without any luck. I'm sure there is a better way to express this query.  The value `XXX` within the is the result of determining which field in the object to use for comparison and is explained below.

Below is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
var paymentReceivedAmt = (from registerEntry in RegisterEntries
    where registerEntry.TransactionType != null
    && registerEntry.TransactionType.Id.SubsystemCode == "A"
    && registerEntry.Receipt != null
    && registerEntry.PostDate != null
    && XXX >= lastInvoicedDate
    select registerEntry.TransactionAmount.GetValueOrDefault(0)).Sum();
```

Value **XXX** =

```
if registerEntry.AddedDate = registerEntry.PostDate
    registerEntry.AddedDate
else
    registerEntry.PostDate
```

The values `registerEntry.AddedDate` and `registerEntry.PostDate` are DateTime type, however when comparing I need to only compare the date and not the time

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: msdn has a lot of good samples : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Did you mean to use assignment instead of equality? `if registerEntry.AddedDate = registerEntry.PostDate` is not the same as `if registerEntry.AddedDate == registerEntry.PostDate` (note the double equal sign)

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use `registerEntry.PostDate` for `XXX`? If it is equal to `registerEntry.AddedDate`, might as well use it and simplify the whole thing

```
var paymentReceivedAmt = (from registerEntry in RegisterEntries
    where registerEntry.TransactionType != null
    && registerEntry.TransactionType.Id.SubsystemCode == "A"
    && registerEntry.Receipt != null
    && registerEntry.PostDate != null
    && registerEntry.PostDate >= lastInvoicedDate
    select registerEntry.TransactionAmount.GetValueOrDefault(0)).Sum();
```

Comment: Thank for your help.  I think I forgot to mention that if the AddedDate was the same value as the PostDate (date only value), I then needed to compare the oldest of the two values against the Invoice date. The PostDate is a DateTime type, however all the times on those values will always be set to 00:00:00 and I couldn't change the code to include the actual time without having severe implications in the rest of the application.   Thanks again though!!!

Comment: @ScottChappa - if `AddedDate` and `PostDate` have the same value, **they are the same date**, there is not one that is older than the other. If your model has the notion of `null` on a `DateTime`, you should be using a nullable one - `DateTime?`.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the LINQ provider you're using you can try the [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator):

```
var paymentReceivedAmt = (from registerEntry in RegisterEntries
    where registerEntry.TransactionType != null
    && registerEntry.TransactionType.Id.SubsystemCode == "A"
    && registerEntry.Receipt != null
    && registerEntry.PostDate != null
    && (registerEntry.AddedDate == registerEntry.PostDate
            ? registerEntry.AddedDate
            : registerEntry.PostDate) >= lastInvoicedDate
    select registerEntry.TransactionAmount.GetValueOrDefault(0)).Sum();
```

Comment: That is it!  I was thinking of a ternary solution, but wasn't sure on how to express it.  Thanks a ton for your help!!!